# Downsample a pandas dataframe keeping same proportion of target in every month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, downsampling

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with column `'TARGET'` which takes values of `0` or `1` and column `'MONTH'` which collects different months:

| MONTH | #_OBS_TARGET=0 | #_OBS_TARGET=1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202207 | 44619 | 52960 |
| 202208 | 48093 | 55399 |
| 202209 | 50161 | 56528 |

I want to downsample my dataframe to have the same number of observations with `TARGET = 0` and `TARGET = 1` **for every value of** `MONTH`:

| MONTH | #_OBS_TARGET=0 | #_OBS_TARGET=1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202207 | 44619 | 44619 |
| 202208 | 48093 | 48093 |
| 202209 | 50161 | 50161 |

I tred the following

```
for m in df['MONTH'].unique():
    number_of_ones = len(df[(df['MONTH']==m) & (df['TARGET']==1)])
    number_of_zeros = len(df[(df['MONTH']==m) & (df['TARGET']==0)])
    n_obs_to_drop = number_of_ones - number_of_zeros 
    df[df['MONTH']==m].drop(df[(df['MONTH']==m) & (df['TARGET']==1)].sample(n_obs_to_drop).index, inplace = True)
```

But clearly it is not deleting anything and I get the following warning (**EDIT2**):

```
/opt/conda/envs/librerias_cbi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4901: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return super().drop(
```

How should I get it? Also a diffent approach is welcomed.

Notice that there are duplicate values of the index in diffent values of `MONTH`. There are also many more columns in `df` which should be kept in the downsampled dataframe.

**EDIT1**:

I'm adding a reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
"MONTH": [202207, 202207, 202207, 202207, 202208, 202208, 202208, 202209, 202209, 202209, 202209],
"TARGET": [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
"other_column1": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110],  # Example additional columns
"other_column2": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100]
}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.crosstab(df['MONTH'],df['TARGET'])

TARGET  0   1
MONTH       
202207  1   3
202208  1   2
202209  2   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the most elegant way but I'll go for

## Get the number of sample for each month

```py
grp = pd.crosstab(df['MONTH'],df['TARGET'])\
    .min(1)\
    .reset_index(name='size')
```

```bash
    MONTH  size
0  202207     1
1  202208     1
2  202209     2
```

## Merge with original df

```py
df1 = pd.merge(df, grp)
```

## Take a sample using size defined before

```py
df2 = df1.groupby(['MONTH', 'TARGET'])\
    .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=x['size'].iloc[0]))\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Your solution works as well as my own answer. Could you please explain why what I did in my question doesn't work? As I understand the only difference is that in my question I was trying to make a change on a slice `df[df['MONTH']==m].drop()`, while in my answer I make a copy and then the change `df_slice.drop()`

Comment: Ciao Ale, i should go through your code to check. I'll have a look next week.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was applying the `.drop()` to each slice of `df`, or something related to duplicate values in the index (for different values of `MONTH`). I solved the problem this way:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame() # create an empty df that will be filled in each iteration of the loop

for mes in df['MONTH'].unique():
    df_slice = df[df["MONTH"]==mes].copy() # create a temporary df where the index is unique
    
    number_of_ones = len(df_slice[df_slice['TARGET']==1])
    number_of_zeros = len(df_slice[df_slice['TARGET']==0])
    n_obs_to_drop = number_of_ones - number_of_zeros
   
    df_slice.drop(df_slice[df_slice['TARGET']==1].sample(n_obs_to_drop).index, inplace = True) # drop rows only for the partition
    
    df_temp = pd.concat([df_temp,df_slice]) # concatenate the partitions

df = df_temp
del df_temp
del df_slice
```